# Ntile function in SQL Server, unexpected output

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012

The query is:

```
create table #t (id int)

insert into #t values(1), (2), (3), (4), (5)

select id, ntile(2) over (order by id desc) 
from #t
```

Result:

```
id  (No column name)  (Expected was)
-------------------------------------
5   1                  1
4   1                  1
3   1                  2
2   2                  2
1   2                  3
```

I was expecting the 3 column result in SQL Server, why is the behavior of it different?

`Ntile(2)` should give 2 number to each?

Comment: `NTILE(2)` splits your result set into ***2*** sets of data (since ***YOU*** asked for it!)  trying to make them as similarly large as possible. If you want to have **3** groups - use `NTILE(3)` :... [see MSDN docs for details on `NTILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx). `NTILE(2)` splits the result set into **2 groups of data** - not into groups of 2 rows each (as you seem to expect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**NTILE**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126(v=sql.110).aspx) technet documentation:

> For each row, NTILE returns *the number of the group* to which the row
>   belongs.

`NTILE(2)` creates *two* groups of data, hence the number returned can only be in `(1,2)`.

You seem to think that `NTILE` returns the *position* of each row within each group, which is clearly not the case.

If you use `NTILE(3)` instead, then **3** groups of data will be created, i.e.

```
 1. `{5, 4}` -> 1st group, 
 2. `{3, 2}` -> 2nd group and
 3. `{1}`    -> 3rd group.
```

Comment: thanks for this: `ntile(N) will only be {1,2,3....N}` right? and not `{1,2,3....N+1}`

Comment: @HareRamaHareKrishna Please check the edit I made for an explanation of `ntile(3)` results.